# How are Hackage package names mapped to 'cabal install' names?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm using cabal to download Haskell packages.

The following works:

```
> cabal install JSON
```

It gets Text.JSON

However, this fails:

```
> cabal install Data.List.Key
cabal: "Data.List.Key" is not valid syntax for a package name or package
dependency.
```

What is the syntax problem here?  How do I make cabal get Data.List.Key?  In general, for a package of name X.Y, what name does `cabal install` need in order to find the package? (I'm confused why `cabal install JSON` gets Text.JSON, and not Foobarbaz.JSON)

Comment: The name used is just the package's name on hackage. For your case `cabal install utility-ht` should work fine. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/utility-ht-0.0.7

Comment: I think the confusion is that what Haskell calls a **module name** is more or less the same as what Java (and probably other languages) call a **package name**. A Haskell module is like a Java package, while a Haskell package is more like what the Java world would call a library or project.

Comment: @MatrixFrog -- yes, that was something that was confusing me.  Thanks!

Comment: I really wish cabal install would use some heuristic to make module name work.  There are a lot of great literate haskell tutorials out there, but before I run any of them, I need to find the package name for each import.  The packages may just be know for experienced users, but they aren't reading the tutorials anyways.

Comment: @Adam How do you expect such a heuristic to work? If you already know what module you're looking for but don't know in which package it is, a quick search on hackage using google or hayoo! will get you there in 5 seconds. If you know neither the package nor the module name - well, if you know at least the functions you're looking for you can still try google or hayoo!. If you don't know these either, no heuristic in the world is going to save you.

Comment: @Cubic if there is only one package with that module name then just install it.  No manual searching on hackage by end user required.  Cabal install would need a way to lookup from module name to packages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `cabal install` command uses package names.  Package names are different from module names.  If you look on the [hackage page for the text package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text), you'll see that the package name is "text", but it exports a module called Data.Text (amongst others).  Packages can export any number of modules and there does not have to be any relationship between the name of the package and the name of the modules it exports.

If you know a package you want, but you don't know the exported modules, look on the hackage page for that package.  To do this, I go to "http://hackage.haskell.org/package/" in my browser.  I've gone there so many times, it auto-completes very quickly, then I add the package name to the end of that url.  If I don't know the exact package name, then I just go to that page and search the package list for what I want.

The converse situation where you know what module you want but don't know what package provides it is a little more difficult.  In this case, I rely on the wonderful Haskell search engine [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/).
(Another one [Hayoo](http://hayoo.info), has been offline for a while.)

Comment: Also, a plain Google search with `site:hackage.haskell.org` usually does a decent job of finding packages. (Although due to PageRank it tends to direct you to older versions of the packages).

Answer (score 1):

Packages can include more than one module. There is no rule about how module names map to package names.

If you know the module name and want to find the package it is in, browse it's hackage documentation.

The url of the module description contains the package name after the `package` part, e.g. the url of Linear.Quaterion is

`http://hackage.haskell.org/package/` `linear-1.21.1` `/docs/Linear-Quaternion.html`

On that page the package name is also shown in the top left end.

If you know the package name, you can query which modules are included with

`cabal info <package name>`.